# Developing for tablets using Phonegap

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, cordova, mobile

i'm starting development with phonegap for tablets and need to clarify some issues.

1) as i understood, i can work in any IDE: Visual Studio, Idea, XCode. All what i need from IDE is emulator to test some specific things, for example interacting with file system, or making JSONP requests to some site's API. Is this true?

2) after developing of application for one single platform, i can take the 'www' folder and build it for other platforms using PhoneGap Build, isn't it?

3) is there any way to emulate tablet in visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need the IDEs for target-platform-specific coding. If you want to make a PhoneGap plugin for Windows Phone, you'd use Visual Studio for the native part. If it were a plugin for iOS, you'd use Xcode.

If you don't want to use PhoneGap Build, you can also build packages for the target platforms using the respective IDEs.

IDEs are also the primary way to test your application, since you can't easily test 
features specific to a mobile device in your browser. If you have the SDKs for your target platforms installed, the respective IDEs should feature a way to run an emulator. You will probably have to set up a project for your app, according to the instructions [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides).

2) Generally, your application should run on any supported platform, as long as you stick to the PhoneGap API. Some features might behave differently on different platforms, so you'll still have to test throroughly on all platforms you indend to support.

3) If you install the [Windows Phone SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402530%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), you can use an emulator. There is some information on what the emulator is capable of on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402563%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

Comment: 3) i'm interesting in tablet emulator, not phone. or i don't know smth about Windows Phone SDK?

Comment: @donRumatta: What kind of tablet OS do you want to emulate?

Comment: i need to develop application for android and ios tablets but i want to work in visual studio and later use phonegap build to prepare packages for target platforms.

Comment: To emulate iOS, you will have to build the package yourself in Xcode in order to be able to run it in the iOS SDK's emulator. On Android, you can use the APK file PhoneGap Build made for you by following [these instructions](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-install-apk-files-android-windows-sdk-emulator). You can't use the emulators directly from within Visual Studio. For the iOS emulator, you even need a Mac, since Xcode is Mac-only.

Comment: i want to use only one IDE and one emulator - visual studio and windows phone emulator and later build application for other platforms using PhoneGap Build. but i'd like to have in visual studio emulator of a tablet not of a phone.

Comment: @donRumatta: Visual Studio 11 has a Windows 8 Simulator, which emulates a tablet with Windows 8 for testing Metro apps. That's as close as you're gonna get to an inside-Visual-Studio-Solution.

Comment: thanks, i think that's what i need. but now i don't sure that phonegap templates work with vs 2011(=